# Break if Scanner reads specific input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner that reads the input but it needs to quit when it reads `'q'`.
The problem is that I can't find a way to do this.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("question 1");
str1 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("question 2");
str2 = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("question 3");
str3 = sc.nextLine();
```

The questions represents user information...
This is just an example code but it demonstrates my problem as soon as the user press <kbd>q</kbd> it must quit. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered taking the user input in a while loop?

Comment: Put it in a while loop, and exit when the exit condition is met (the user entered 'q'). If you need it to go over a set of questions, you can loop over a List of questions, with the exit condition being either them entering 'q', or the list being exhausted; which ever comes first.

Comment: You can write a while loop that will keep asking questions until (or unless) the user types q in the sc.nextline().

Comment: Yes I did but is there not a fancier way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's done like this

```
String input = "";
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (!(input = scan.nextLine()).equals("q")) {
    // store the input (example - you can store however you want) 
    list.add(input);
}
```

but in your case, you could also incorporate a list of questions that you can cycle through.

```
ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
questions.add("q1");
questions.add("q2");
questions.add("q3");

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

String input = "";
ArrayList<String> userInput = new ArrayList<String>();
int index = 0;

// print the first question and increment the index
System.out.println(questions.get(index));
index++;

while (!(input = scan.nextLine()).equals("q")) {
    // store the input (example - you can store however you want) 
    userInput.add(input);

    // print the next question since the user didn't enter q
    // if there are no questions left, stop asking
    if (index == questions.size() - 1) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(questions.get(index));

    // keep track of the index!!
    index++;
}

scan.close();
```

At the end of the question asking, you can use the values in the list of userInputs. Answers are stored starting from index 0, and correspond to the matching question list.

On a side note, if you actually wanted to detect when the user pressed "q" before he pressed enter, you could implement a KeyListener on the q button... (however, this would stop the program every time the user's valid input started with a q) see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html for more detail

Answer (score 0):

The person before me is correct, but you might also try

```
String input = ""
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (true){
     input = sc.nextLine();
     if (input.equals("q"))
         break;
     list.add(input)
}
```

is more readable and your intentions for stopping the code are far more clear.

Hope this helps.